# the Console.Write get's printed in a loop, and appears before all the input has been submited

Tags: c#

this is the input I'm using:

```
Bread Juice Fruits Lemons 
10 50 20 30
2.34 1.23 3.42 1.50
Bread
Juice
done
```

this is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace List.Store
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            string quantity = Console.ReadLine();
            string price = Console.ReadLine();
            List<string> names = name.Split(" ").ToList();
            List<long> quantities = quantity.Split(" ").Select(long.Parse).ToList();
            List<double> prices = price.Split(" ").Select(double.Parse).ToList();
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            while(input != "done")
            {
                for (int a = 0; a < names.Count; a++)
                {
                    if (names[a] ==  input)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{input} costs {prices[a]}; Available quantity: {quantities[a]}");
                    }
                    input = Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is the output I want to receive:

```
Bread costs: 2.34; Available quantity: 10
Juice costs: 1.23; Available quantity: 50
```

this is the output I'm receiving:
[image]
The problem is that the 1st and 2nd message is getting printed before the "done" command. I don't know if that is a problem, but still, I'm writing this. Usually, I will move the Console.WriteLine outside of the loop, but I need it to be inside that loop so I can print the right thing with the variable "a".

Comment: For one thing, I very much doubt that you want the second `input = Console.ReadLine();` call *inside the loop*. But I'm still not sure what you're trying to achieve. If you want the user to enter all the things they're interested in before you do any of your matching, you need to have that in one loop, retaining that input in a list (or similar), then have the matching part.

Comment: If you want to output _after_ you entered "done", you have basically two choices here: Either you collect the outputs before outputting them, and output them _after_ you entered "done". Or, you collect all the inputs without processing them, and only process them after you entered "done". You can't call Console.WriteLine and then somehow expect to find some trick that somehow keeps Console.WriteLine from acting like Console.WriteLine. (I mean, technically you could replace Console's output TextReader with a dirty evil custom TextReader implementing such dirty tricks, if that's your gig...)

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace the problem is that I don't know how many of the food command the user will use. With my current input, it's only "bread" and "juice", so I can technically make 2 strings to keep the 2 Console.WriteLine texts and then print them after the cycle, but what if it wasn't only "bread" and "juice" and the user decides to write a 3rd command for "Lemons" for example? I don't know how to create infinite number of strings to hold the values, so I expect someone to give me that type of fix.

Comment: "_collect_" is the crucial word here. With regard to .NET nomenclature, collections are used to collect things. If you don't know about the common kinds of collections offered by the .NET class library, perhaps it would be a good time to seek a tutorial about .NET collections so as to familiarize yourself with the common collection types available for use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fully OOP solution check the commented lines comments.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


namespace Store
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            //UNCOMMENT TO BE ABLE TO TYPE
            /*
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            string quantity = Console.ReadLine();
            string price = Console.ReadLine();

            */
            //COMMENT TO DO WHAT IS ABOVE
            string name = "Bread Juice Fruits Lemons";
            string quantity = "10 50 20 30";
            string price = "2.34 1.23 3.42 1.50";
            //END COMMENT WHAT IS ABOVE

            List<string> names = name.Split(Convert.ToChar(" ")).ToList();            
            List<long> quantities = quantity.Split(Convert.ToChar(" ")).Select(long.Parse).ToList();
            List<double> prices = price.Split(Convert.ToChar(" ")).Select(double.Parse).ToList();

            List<Store> stores = new List<Store>();
            if (names.Count == quantities.Count && quantities.Count == prices.Count)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<names.Count;i++)
                {
                    Store store = new Store();
                    store.Name = names[i];
                    store.Quantity = quantities[i];
                    store.Price = prices[i];
                    stores.Add(store);
                }            
            }
            
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            while (input != "done")
            {
                var store =stores.Find(x => x.Name == input);
                Console.WriteLine(store.ToString());
                input=Console.ReadLine();
             
            }
            
        }
    }

    public class Store {

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public long Quantity { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{this.Name} costs {this.Price}; Available quantity: {this.Quantity}";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I found a much simpler solution for me to the problem by just adding another List to hold all the lines I should print and then using List.Add in the loop instead of printing, and at the end outside of any loop I print the list, but you are the one who opened my eyes to do it while looking at your code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I added a list to save all searched items and at the end I print the list. I added a class to save all the stuff.

```
string name = Console.ReadLine();
string quantity = Console.ReadLine();
string price = Console.ReadLine();
List<string> names = name.Split(" ").ToList();
List<long> quantities = quantity.Split(" ").Select(long.Parse).ToList();
List<double> prices = price.Split(" ").Select(double.Parse).ToList();
string input = Console.ReadLine();
List<Product> searchedItems = new List<Product>();

while (input != "done")
{
    int index = names.FindIndex(x => x == input);
    if (index != -1)
        searchedItems.Add(new Product() { Name = names[index], Price = prices[index], Quantity = quantities[index] });

    input = Console.ReadLine();

}
searchedItems.ForEach(item =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Name} costs {item.Price}; Available quantity: {item.Quantity}");
});


class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long Quantity { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```